# Using Blender in the background IN Jupyter Notebook on MacOS

Tags: terminal, jupyter-notebook, blender

Note* I use Python 3.9.2 and Blender 3.3.1.

Hello, so my goal is to be able to run Blender in the background in Jupyter Notebook. The problem I come across is running Blender within Jupyter Notebook. I can't "import bpy".

I have been following documentation online but I have been unable to figure out why it won't run. Here is a link to what I was following:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/172249/how-can-i-use-blenders-python-api-from-a-ipython-terminal-or-jupyter-notebook

When I run this in my terminal, it says that it requires Python 3.7. How would I go about fixing this?

Once this is resolved, would I just open a blender notebook with Jupyter Notebook and then it should run fine? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This question belongs on [blender stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/), not stackoverflow.

You get the error message that you need python 3.7, because the tooling you are trying to use is made for Blender 2.8.x, which uses that version of python. You have Blender 3.3 with python3.10.

You can either switch Blender version, or you can configure Blender to run with another Python interpreter. This latter option might be OK for Blender 3.3 (dont bet on it).Custom addons are very likely to break to begin with.